Proxy pass two webapp on the same server
I have two nextjs apps that is running using pm2. My first app is running in port 3000 then the second app is running in port 4000. I want to configure all traffics going to http://public_ip to the first app running in port 3000 (e.g. http://62.32.188.222) while route all traffics going to http://public_ip/web to the second app running in port 4000 (e.g. http://62.32.188.222/web). Take note that the second app has a base/root path of /web and the landing page is /web/sign-in
Here is my nginx config
upstream backend {
   least_conn;
   server 192.168.1.2:8080;
   server 192.168.1.3:8080;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name 62.32.188.222;

   location / {
      #proxy headers
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
   }

   location /web {
      #proxy headers
      proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/web/sign-in;
   }

   ###omit other location block
}
       

I have no problem when accessing the public_ip it goes correctly to the first app running in port 3000, but when I try to access public_url/web it throws 404 and updates the url to public_url/sign-in..
Based on nginx's access.log it goes to the app in port 3000. Can someone help me? TIA
